# How to transfer pam.d config paramenter with ansible without craching authentification on server?

Tags: linux, ansible

i have faced a problem, and i am asking for help.
I need to lock users after multiple login fails with ansible. In order to do so, i need to change 2 files on my ubuntu 22 **'common-account'** and **'common-auth'**. When i do in manually, everything works fine.

Just have to add 1 line in **'common-account'**:

```
account required pam_faillock.so
```

And 3 lines in **'common-auth'**

```
# existed comment lines in file
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=3 unlock_time=120 fail_interval=60
# existed comment lines in file
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 unlock_time=120 fail_interval=60
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=3 unlock_time=120 fail_interval=60
#another existed config parameters in file
```

But when i need to automate this with ansible i encounter an **problem**. **FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}**
This happens because ansible is changing **'common-auth'** only one line during one ssh connection. And, after this "auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail ..." line is added, i have got an error above.

I have tried several methods, with different ansible modules (pamd, lineinfile, assemble, loop, with_item) but, problems remains. You can find code for 2 of my approaches below. First one is with with_item, second with pamd.

```html
---

- name: Number of tries during loging account
  lineinfile:
     state: present
     dest: '{{ pamd_account_file_ub }}'
     regexp: '^{{ item.search }}'
     line: '{{ item.replace }}'
  with_items:
      - { search: 'account required pam_faillock.so', replace: 'account required pam_faillock.so' }

- name: Number of tries during loging auth preauth
  community.general.pamd:
    name: common-auth
    type: auth
    control: '[success=1 default=ignore]'
    module_path: pam_unix.so
    new_type: auth
    new_control: required
    new_module_path: pam_faillock.so
    module_arguments:
     - 'preauth'
     - 'audit'
     - 'silent'
     - 'deny={{ number_of_login_try_before_block }}'
     - 'unlock_time={{ unlock_time }}'
     - 'fail_interval={{ fail_interval }}'
    state: before

- name: Number of tries during loging auth authfail authsucc 
  lineinfile:
     state: present
     dest: '{{ pamd_auth_file_ub }}'
     regexp: '^{{ item.search }}'
     insertafter: 'auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok'
     line: '{{ item.replace }}'
  with_items:
      - { search: 'auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail}}', replace: 'auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny={{ number_of_login_try_before_block }} unlock_time={{ unlock_time }} fail_interval={{ fail_interval }}' }
      - { search: 'auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc', replace: 'auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny={{ number_of_login_try_before_block }} unlock_time={{ unlock_time }} fail_interval={{ fail_interval }}' }
```

```html
---

- name: Number of tries during loging account
  lineinfile:
     state: present
     dest: '{{ pamd_account_file_ub }}'
     regexp: '^{{ item.search }}'
     line: '{{ item.replace }}'
  with_items:
      - { search: 'account required pam_faillock.so', replace: 'account required pam_faillock.so' }

- name: Number of tries during loging auth preauth
  community.general.pamd:
    name: common-auth
    type: auth
    control: '[success=1 default=ignore]'
    module_path: pam_unix.so
    new_type: auth
    new_control: required
    new_module_path: pam_faillock.so
    module_arguments:
     - 'preauth'
     - 'audit'
     - 'silent'
     - 'deny={{ number_of_login_try_before_block }}'
     - 'unlock_time={{ unlock_time }}'
     - 'fail_interval={{ fail_interval }}'
    state: before

- name: Number of tries during loging auth authfail
  community.general.pamd:
    name: common-auth
    type: auth
    control: requisite
    module_path: pam_deny.so
    new_type: auth
    new_control: sufficient
    new_module_path: pam_faillock.so
    state: before

- name: Number of tries during loging auth authsucc
  community.general.pamd:
    name: common-auth
    type: auth
    control: '[success=1 default=ignore]'
    module_path: pam_unix.so
    new_type: auth
    new_control: '[default=die]'
    new_module_path: pam_faillock.so
    state: after
```

I can just copy file from my local machine to destination server, but in that way i can accidentally delete some existing configuration lines.

Summarizing my question.

**How to make sure, that configuration parameters are present in the file (if not add, if yes change) and send them in one ssh connection?**

Any answer will be helpful and appreciated, and thank you for your guidance in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, i have found solution.

You may use ansible `blockinfile` module with `insertbefore` and `insertafter`

If your pam.d configuration lines cannot be placed in one block you need to figure our way to edit pam.d file with out breaking login

For our case it was `auth required pam_faillock.so preauth` before `pam_unix.so` module and then `blockinfile` with modules below

```
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc
```

it was inserted before `pam_deny.so` module